# SQL1476N The current transaction was rolled back because of error "-30080". SQLSTATE=40506

Tags: db2, zos

Hi I am getting SQL error -30080 while running a select query on datastage, on google I cannot fing SQL error -30080, can you provide me the reason

Comment: Will you please give some more detail about your error?

Comment: May be referencing the product manual could help? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n30080.dita?lang=en

Comment: @Lafada what other details i can give you ?

Comment: @mustaccio it is for ql state 08001 ,but for me sql state is 40506

Comment: SQL1476N The current transaction was rolled back because of error "-30080". SQLSTATE=40506

Comment: You need to ask the DBA to examine the Db2-server diagnostics around the same time as the message you got (SQL1476N, -30080, sqlstate 40506).  You need to find the real underlying error that caused the sqlstate 40506. The diagnostics location depends on the operating-system on which the Db2-server runs (Z/Os, i-series,  Unix/Windows), missing from your question. Once you know the underlying cause you can then get the correct person to address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQL30080N 
A communication error “” occurred sending or receiving data from the remote database.

40506:
 The current transaction was rolled back because of an SQL error.